# Are there magical movies in Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter*, moving pictures are quite common, and seem to be even cheaper and easier to produce than in Muggle society. There are moving pictures in the *Daily Prophet*, in the book Hagrid gave to Harry at the end of his first year at Hogwarts, and in many other places. I seem to vaguely recall there also being animated sketches and possibly an animated stained glass window.

Do the witches and wizards of Potterverse make any longer animations? Do they make any magical movies or magical short films or magical recorded lectures?

There's the Pensieve, of course, for viewing stored memories, but I'm more interested in applications of the same sort of magic that they use to make the more ordinary animated photographs.

Comment: Considering that the primary forms of the wizarding entertainment industry is radio and theater, I would guess not.